# GPS POIs and point of view

Tags: php, gps

Thanks to Cosines or Haversine formulas, I get a list of POIs ordered by there distance from where I am.

How can I get to the next level and select the POIs that correspond to the direction I'm looking at (let's say 15°+/-5°, 0=North, 90=East)?

There is not much code already. We could use an exemple like this

```
$gps_pos = array (
                 'lat'=>48.845364, 
                 'lng'=>2.406628, 
                 'distance'=>20);
$pois = GetPOIsFromGPS($gps_pos);
```

There $pois looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 336047
            [gps_lat] => 48.84528500
            [gps_lng] => 2.40663900
            [gps_alt] => 0.0000
            [distance_in_kms] => 0.0088094293255129
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 955092
            [gps_lat] => 48.84520700
            [gps_lng] => 2.40657700
            [gps_alt] => 0.0000
            [distance_in_kms] => 0.017828309444397
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1022839
            [gps_lat] => 48.84515700
            [gps_lng] => 2.40644600
            [gps_alt] => 0.0000
            [distance_in_kms] => 0.026556875382492
        )
)
```

The trick is now to make de GetPOIsInPOV function.

```
$pov = array ('hdegres' => 15, 'range'=>5);

$pois_in_pov = GetPOIsInPOV($pois, $pov);
```

Thanks

Comment: You tagged this with `php` – have you made any attempts in PHP yet? Any code to share?

Comment: edited with some code because I don't know at all how to limit the POIs to match de point of view... I should have done more math, i guess...